# Graph API Batch request not working for GET

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request

Following batch request doesn't work:

https://graph.facebook.com/?batch%3d[{%22method%22%3a%22get%22%2c%22relative_url%22%3a%22me%22}%2c%22{%22method%22%3a%22get%22%2c%22relative_url%22%3a%22me%2ffriends%3flimit%3d50%22}]%26access_token%3d

It has a valid access token & I have encoded it using UTF-8 to see if that works, but I get

{

```
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
}
```

}

Can somebody please tell me if Graph API supports only GET for Batch requests? thanks in advance